# products in a unique factorisation domain.

Tags: ring-theory, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

I'm learning a proof about UFD's but I'm not following this particular part:

Given a ring A which is a UFD, with a non-zero non-unit element p which is a prime element.

Then if you take an arbitrary product ab from (p) (proper non zero ideal), you can deduce there is c such that ab = pc.

Now the proof states that due to the unique factorisation property, we have that either a or b is divisible by p, that is to say that you can write just one of them as a product of p and something else. Meaning a is in (p) or b is in (p)

I don't understand how we deduced this, surely both of them could have a unique factorisation which has p? i.e c = p(e...f)(g...h) so a = p(e...f) and b = p(g...h)

Comment: If the proof really intends "$a$ or $b$ but not both," then the proof is clearly wrong, as any numerical example in the integers will show.

Comment: So does this mean when it reads either a or b I should take it to mean a or b or both?

Comment: Yes, this "or" is not exclusive or: it means $a$ or $b$ or possibly both

Answer (score 1):

Almost invariably, in mathematical communication, “Α or B” is understood to include the case where both are true. So, yes, they could both have a unique factorisation involving $p$.

Comment: Yes, but "either $a$ or $b$" is usually understood to be the "exclusive-or" which excludes the case where both are true.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I don't think the statement "if $ab = 0$ then either $a = 0$ or $b = 0$" is untrue.

Comment: You may be right, but if I were writing a textbook, I wouldn't write it that way. It's just too easy for a student to misinterpret or get confused.